# Excel - take formatting from another cell

Tags: excel

I have a table of data

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F(takes the max from each line)
1  3.93 2.09 2.49 0.89 1.11  3.93                       
2  0.97 0.34 0.69 0.08 1.06  1.06                
3  4.21 4.40 2.90 1.14 1.45  4.40                    
...
```

Columns from A to E contains values which also have associated formatting (some numbers are red, other orange etc.).

Column F has a `max()` formula to get the maximum value from each row of the table.

What I want to do, is getting also the format of the cell where the max occurs. Is there an automatic way to do it?

I have seen it is possible via a macro (I am not familiar with macros, so actually even the code in the example is not fully clear to me): [excel macro](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4225-excel-reference-format-in-another-cell.html), however my case is complicated by the fact that the cells in F can get values from anyone of the cells in the corresponding row, depending where the maximum occurs. Therefore I cannot just say "copy format of cell A1 into cell E2" as in the example I linked.

What I would do is:

```
If .Range("F1").Value2 = "A1" Then
    Range("F1").Copy (.Range("A1"))
else 
    If .Range("F1").Value2 = "B1" Then
    Range("F1").Copy (.Range("B1"))
else 
    If .Range("F1").Value2 = "C1" Then
    Range("F1").Copy (.Range("C1"))   
else 
    If .Range("F1").Value2 = "D1" Then
    Range("F1").Copy (.Range("D1"))
else 
    If .Range("F1").Value2 = "E1" Then
    Range("F1").Copy (.Range("E1"))
End If
```

Moreover, I want to do it for each value in column F. Do I need a for-cycle?
So, for example it should then become:

```
For i = 1 To 235
    If .Range("Fi").Value2 = "Ai" Then
    Range("Fi").Copy (.Range("Ai"))
... and so on with all the conditions
```

Is this the way to go?

Comment: Use MATCH to find the value, e.g.in the first row 3.93 is in first cell so copy that cell and paste formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SJR has the right idea.

Here is that idea implemented in code.

```
Sub colorMe()

    For i = 1 To 235
        Cells(i, WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A" & i & ":E" & i)), Range("A" & i & ":E" & i), 0)).Copy
        Cells(i, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Next i

End Sub
```

Here is the final result: [Macro Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Uu7.png)

Hope this helps!